# automatic create of capture file (for wireshark)

Tags: windows, networking, network-monitor

Is there any program for windows, that create a capture file (of the actual session) for Wireshark?

Comment: What do you mean automatic? Does it need to be command line? Does it need to be runnable as a Windows Service?

Comment: What budget? Free? Open source?

Comment: Command Line would be perfect. Somethong like a bash script. And yes, Windows Service. No Budget, free and it dowsn't has to be open sorce. But scapy is all of this.

Comment: Please include that into the body of your question, comments get deleted. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wireshark can capture itself of course but you can also use [scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/) to capture from the command line or from a script and can save to a wireshark format.

scapy is:

- Free, gratis & open source
- Cross Platform
- Very powerful, you can do a lot more than simple captures.